# focus() jQuery function doesn't work in Safari, but works fine on all other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, focus, textfield

I have a search text field and search button, when button is clicked with default text in text field, or null value, an alert pops up and sets focus back on search text field. This works very well on all major browsers but not in safari.

I tried it even with out jquery, but didn't work. When the focus falls on search text field, I have another jQuery function, is that the problem.

The code that sets focus on search text is:

```
if (defaults.keyword == SEARCH_TIP || defaults.keyword == '') {
    alert(SEARCH_NULL);
    $('#store_search_keyword').focus();
    return false;
}
```

The code on focus is:

```
var search_dom = $('#store_search_keyword');
var search_text = search_dom.val();
search_dom.focus(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === SEARCH_TIP) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

any help is appreciated, thanks..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913175

Answer (score 2):

You should call the native DOM `focus()` method, like this:

```
document.getElementByID('store_search_keyword').focus();
```

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. I have another function upon focus, I'm not sure is that the cause of all these troubles?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work properly in Safari.

http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com/2010/05/safari-focus-and-popup-alerts.html

The problem is caused by that "alert()" in your handler. Safari doesn't realize that its main window regains focus after the alert box is cleared, and when Safari doesn't think it's the focused application it pays no attention to `.focus()` calls on *anything*.

Comment: But I have this problem too even WITHOUT using alert()
I've tried to use the following function (using jQuery) in a button click event:

  setTimeout( function() { $("#input_name")[0].focus(); }, 2000)

When the user clicks in another input element e.g. "#input_zip" after clicking the button, Safari on iOS will show the onscreen keyboard. After two seconds "#input_zip" will loose the focus, the keyboard disappears but "#input_name" will never get the focus !?!?!

Comment: Perhaps the appearance of the keyboard has an effect similar to that of the "alert()" dialog.  Safari thinks it's not the foreground "application" because of the keyboard, so it ignores your calls to ".focus()".  (I don't know that for sure, and I've never done mobile web stuff, but I do know that Safari is really firm about refusing calls to "focus()" when it's not the foreground application, and it's pretty dumb about it too in at least the "alert()" case.)